# Integral extension is a finitely generated $R$-module?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ are  elements of a ring $R'$ (commutative) which are integral over $R$ then $R[b_1,\ldots,b_n]$  is a f.g. $R$-module.

**My question is:** If $\{b_i\}_{i\in I}$ are elements integral over $R$, is then $R[\{b_i\}_{i\in I}]$ a f.g $R$-module?

Thanks for any counterexample.

Comment: Is $R'$ commutative? Is $I$ finite? If $I$ is not finite, then the answer is "no" and you can take, e.g., the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ as a counterexample. If $R'$ is not commutative, then the square-brackets notations need further explanation, but probably the answer again will be "no".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algebraic closure $\overline {\mathbf Q}\,$ of $\mathbf Q$ is not finitely generated over $\mathbf Q$ (as a vector space) since there exists irreducible polynomials of arbitrary degree.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot adjoin an infinite number of elements and expect the module is still finitely generated. Take $R= \mathbb{Z}$ and  $b_i = 2^{1/2^i}$ for example.